# How can I trim the process path from output?

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a PowerShell script to output the process,

```
$Process=chknull $_.Properties[0].Value
$Process_new=$Process -replace '(?<!  .*) ','_'
```

The above code outputs the result as entire path of process, Eg:

`C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe.`

Is there a way, where I can get just "Notepad.exe"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting a full path return like that as a string you can set the value into a variable and then use split on it and grab the last entry in the resulting array.

Example:

```
("C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe." -split "\\")[-1]
```

Remember to use two "\" as it is also an escape character in regex.

Comment: This worked for me, Thank You Jason.

Answer (score 0):

```
([IO.FileInfo]"C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe").Name
```

Comment: Not worth the other answer but I would have done this: `[io.path]::GetFileName("C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe")` The jist being used methods that will do the work for you.